# Thread auto starting

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe3

My thread class is auto starting although the suspended property is set to true. 
I have a base class which as an array of the thread class. Here is my class declaration.

```
Type

cSolution = Class(TThread)
Private
procedure FindLocalMinimum;
procedure AddWorker;
procedure RandomSortCompressors;
procedure FindBestNetwork;

Public
Network : cNetwork;
Workers : array of cWorker;
Compressors : array of cCompressorData;
IsAllWorkersDone : boolean;
ID : integer;

Procedure CreateWorkers;
Constructor Create; overload;   // This constructor uses defaults
Constructor Create(aNetwork : cNetwork; aCompressors : array of cCompressorData); overload; // Copy constructor
 Destructor  Destroy; override; //Destructor

procedure Execute; override;
end;

implementation
/// <summary>Default constructer
/// </summary>
constructor cSolution.Create;
begin
    inherited;
    IsAllWorkersDone := false;
    Suspended := true;
    ID := 99;
end;
```

I added breakpoints to the place where I call the execute function, and at the beginning of the execute function. The place where I call it is never triggered. But the break point in the execute function itself is triggered. When it is triggered the suspended property is false.

Is there something I am missing or why is the thread auto starting when I don't want it to auto start.

Comment: Hint: `Execute` should be overriden as a protected method, not promoted to public. Making it public is risky as other code could call it directly, which could cause unexpected "effects".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `inherited Create(True)` in your constructor. This will avoid starting the thread.

Setting `Suspended` to `True` after calling `inherited Create()` will still result in starting the thread (Delphi has a couple of bugs in that area...)

Comment: do you mean it can run before Suspended := True ... or that Suspended := true is ignored?

Comment: thanks This works. I though that setting the suspended  property to true was the same as calling create (true)

Comment: There's no "Delphi bug" here. The issue is incorrectly calling the constructor, which creates the thread in the default (non-suspended) state. The thread would already (correctly) be running before `Suspended := True;` is ever called. (You can't blame Delphi for a "bug" caused by something you do incorrectly in your own code.)

Comment: As far as I can see this isn't exactly true.  In all cases (at least in a windows environment) the thread is created in a suspended state and only started in the AfterConstruction method.  This would mean that setting the FCreateSuspended field in the constructor would work but this is of course a private field.  In fact the reason that the original code doesn't work is because it is suspending the thread before it has been started in AfterConstruction.

Comment: @Kanitatlan: however, a Windows thread has a suspend count associated with it. `Create(False)` would create the thread suspended (count=1), then `Suspended:=true` would call `SuspendThread()` (count=2), then `TThread.AfterConstruction()` would call `ResumeThread()` (count=1) and the thread would not run until `ResumeThread()` is called again (count=0).

Comment: @Remy: Only that `TThread.AfterConstruction()` calls `InternalStart()` which contains `FSuspended := false` (please note that it's not using the property!). Because of this `Suspended := false` later on will not call `ResumeThread()` anymore.